STM32H7 trigger at falling edge of PWM signal
I'd like to trigger a GPIO when detecting a falling edge on my PWM.
I want to do all of this within the same timer.
For example:
Timer 1: PWM Generation
Timer 2: input capture indirect mode or something that would allow me to detect the falling edge.
I want to do it fully in software (no hardware wire between Channel 1 and Channel 2' GPIOs and just use a simple input capture).
I'm using a NUCLEO-H753ZI.
Thanks
